# How to display data from multiple table using knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to display data from relation table using knockout JS. I have the following JSON

```
[
    {
        "Land": {
            "Description": "Fairfax land",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "LandID": 1,
        "ZoningID": 1,
        "InsuranceID": 1,
        "MapNum": "M-452658",
        "TaxDistrict": 8754,
        "LandArea": 526.36,
        "Utilities": "Temp",
        "IsRoadPaved": true,
        "SiteCondition": "GOOD",
        "LandAssesmentValue": 5.32,
        "BuildingAssesmentValue": 4.56,
        "BuildingUsage": "Yes",
        "Style": "NT",
        "ExteriorWallMaterial": "TY",
        "Roof": "KI",
        "Basement": "GBH",
        "BasementSize": 452.3,
        "YearBuilt": "/Date(1138766400000)/",
        "YearAddition": "/Date(1329278400000)/",
        "YearRemodeled": "/Date(1359864000000)/",
        "BedRoom": 4,
        "FullBath": 3,
        "HalfBath": 2,
        "FirePlace": 3,
        "BasementRoom": 5,
        "Heating": "GRF",
        "ConstructionQuality": "BETTER",
        "PhysicalCondition": "GOOD",
        "HasSwimmingPool": true,
        "SwimmingPoolSize": 25.1,
        "WoodDeck": 23.5,
        "Porch": 21,
        "Garagae": 2,
        "PurchasePrice": 847.32,
        "PurchaseDate": "/Date(1202788800000)/",
        "SalePrice": 5871.2,
        "SaleDate": "/Date(1327204800000)/",
        "IsManagementAssociation": true,
        "ManagementName": "GTR",
        "ManagementAddress": "King Street",
        "ManagementPhone": "58758",
        "ManagementFee": 500,
        "PolicyNumber": "P-0121",
        "ID": 1,
        "CreateDate": "/Date(1357963200000)/",
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "UpdateDate": null,
        "UpdatedBy": null
    },
    {
        "Land": {
            "Description": "Fairfax land",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Zoning": {
            "Description": "VA Zoning",
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "Insurence": {
            "CompanyName": "Geico",
            "Address": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdateDate": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null
        },
        "LandID": 1,
        "ZoningID": 1,
        "InsuranceID": 1,
        "MapNum": "M-452658",
        "TaxDistrict": 8754,
        "LandArea": 526.36,
        "Utilities": "Temp",
        "IsRoadPaved": true,
        "SiteCondition": "GOOD",
        "LandAssesmentValue": 5.32,
        "BuildingAssesmentValue": 4.56,
        "BuildingUsage": "Yes",
        "Style": "NT",
        "ExteriorWallMaterial": "TY",
        "Roof": "KI",
        "Basement": "GBH",
        "BasementSize": 452.3,
        "YearBuilt": "/Date(1138766400000)/",
        "YearAddition": "/Date(1329278400000)/",
        "YearRemodeled": "/Date(1359864000000)/",
        "BedRoom": 4,
        "FullBath": 3,
        "HalfBath": 2,
        "FirePlace": 3,
        "BasementRoom": 5,
        "Heating": "GRF",
        "ConstructionQuality": "BETTER",
        "PhysicalCondition": "GOOD",
        "HasSwimmingPool": true,
        "SwimmingPoolSize": 25.1,
        "WoodDeck": 23.5,
        "Porch": 21,
        "Garagae": 2,
        "PurchasePrice": 847.32,
        "PurchaseDate": "/Date(1202788800000)/",
        "SalePrice": 5871.2,
        "SaleDate": "/Date(1327204800000)/",
        "IsManagementAssociation": true,
        "ManagementName": "GTR",
        "ManagementAddress": "King Street",
        "ManagementPhone": "58758",
        "ManagementFee": 500,
        "PolicyNumber": "P-0121",
        "ID": 2,
        "CreateDate": "/Date(1357963200000)/",
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "UpdateDate": null,
        "UpdatedBy": null
    }
]
```

Now instead of LandID I want to display Description from Land class and when click add/edit this land data will be display as dropdownlist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `this land data`. Do you mean the properties of just the Land object, the individual objects representing Zoning and Insurence (sp) and their properties, the elements (i.e. LandID, ZoningID) within the base object, or all of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

In your ViewModel function like

```
self.list1 = ko.observableArray([{"Land":{"Description":"Fairfax land","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Zoning":{"Description":"VA Zoning","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Insurence":{"CompanyName":"Geico","Address":null,"Phone":null,"ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"LandID":1,"ZoningID":1,"InsuranceID":1,"MapNum":"M-452658","TaxDistrict":8754,"LandArea":526.36,"Utilities":"Temp","IsRoadPaved":true,"SiteCondition":"GOOD","LandAssesmentValue":5.32,"BuildingAssesmentValue":4.56,"BuildingUsage":"Yes","Style":"NT","ExteriorWallMaterial":"TY","Roof":"KI","Basement":"GBH","BasementSize":452.3,"YearBuilt":"\/Date(1138766400000)\/","YearAddition":"\/Date(1329278400000)\/","YearRemodeled":"\/Date(1359864000000)\/","BedRoom":4,"FullBath":3,"HalfBath":2,"FirePlace":3,"BasementRoom":5,"Heating":"GRF","ConstructionQuality":"BETTER","PhysicalCondition":"GOOD","HasSwimmingPool":true,"SwimmingPoolSize":25.1,"WoodDeck":23.5,"Porch":21,"Garagae":2,"PurchasePrice":847.32,"PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1202788800000)\/","SalePrice":5871.2,"SaleDate":"\/Date(1327204800000)\/","IsManagementAssociation":true,"ManagementName":"GTR","ManagementAddress":"King Street","ManagementPhone":"58758","ManagementFee":500,"PolicyNumber":"P-0121","ID":1,"CreateDate":"\/Date(1357963200000)\/","CreatedBy":1,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},{"Land":{"Description":"Fairfax land","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Zoning":{"Description":"VA Zoning","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Insurence":{"CompanyName":"Geico","Address":null,"Phone":null,"ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"LandID":1,"ZoningID":1,"InsuranceID":1,"MapNum":"M-452658","TaxDistrict":8754,"LandArea":526.36,"Utilities":"Temp","IsRoadPaved":true,"SiteCondition":"GOOD","LandAssesmentValue":5.32,"BuildingAssesmentValue":4.56,"BuildingUsage":"Yes","Style":"NT","ExteriorWallMaterial":"TY","Roof":"KI","Basement":"GBH","BasementSize":452.3,"YearBuilt":"\/Date(1138766400000)\/","YearAddition":"\/Date(1329278400000)\/","YearRemodeled":"\/Date(1359864000000)\/","BedRoom":4,"FullBath":3,"HalfBath":2,"FirePlace":3,"BasementRoom":5,"Heating":"GRF","ConstructionQuality":"BETTER","PhysicalCondition":"GOOD","HasSwimmingPool":true,"SwimmingPoolSize":25.1,"WoodDeck":23.5,"Porch":21,"Garagae":2,"PurchasePrice":847.32,"PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1202788800000)\/","SalePrice":5871.2,"SaleDate":"\/Date(1327204800000)\/","IsManagementAssociation":true,"ManagementName":"GTR","ManagementAddress":"King Street","ManagementPhone":"58758","ManagementFee":500,"PolicyNumber":"P-0121","ID":2,"CreateDate":"\/Date(1357963200000)\/","CreatedBy":1,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null}]);
```

and your html structure like this

```
<div data-bind="foreach : list1">
    <div data-bind="with: Land">
        <div data-bind="text : Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...Could you please tell me how can I manage this land in edit or add mode. I mean that time this should be dropdownlist and edit mode select the desire land.

Comment: @Andy....can we use nested foreach instead of with binding?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that in help in Option binding.
If want to add you can push method

and you can change selection using `selectedOptions` attribute

Your JS file

```
self.list1 = ko.observableArray([{"Land":{"Description":"Fairfax land","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Zoning":{"Description":"VA Zoning","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Insurence":{"CompanyName":"Geico","Address":null,"Phone":null,"ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"LandID":1,"ZoningID":1,"InsuranceID":1,"MapNum":"M-452658","TaxDistrict":8754,"LandArea":526.36,"Utilities":"Temp","IsRoadPaved":true,"SiteCondition":"GOOD","LandAssesmentValue":5.32,"BuildingAssesmentValue":4.56,"BuildingUsage":"Yes","Style":"NT","ExteriorWallMaterial":"TY","Roof":"KI","Basement":"GBH","BasementSize":452.3,"YearBuilt":"\/Date(1138766400000)\/","YearAddition":"\/Date(1329278400000)\/","YearRemodeled":"\/Date(1359864000000)\/","BedRoom":4,"FullBath":3,"HalfBath":2,"FirePlace":3,"BasementRoom":5,"Heating":"GRF","ConstructionQuality":"BETTER","PhysicalCondition":"GOOD","HasSwimmingPool":true,"SwimmingPoolSize":25.1,"WoodDeck":23.5,"Porch":21,"Garagae":2,"PurchasePrice":847.32,"PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1202788800000)\/","SalePrice":5871.2,"SaleDate":"\/Date(1327204800000)\/","IsManagementAssociation":true,"ManagementName":"GTR","ManagementAddress":"King Street","ManagementPhone":"58758","ManagementFee":500,"PolicyNumber":"P-0121","ID":1,"CreateDate":"\/Date(1357963200000)\/","CreatedBy":1,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},
            {"Land":{"Description":"Fairfax land 2","ID":2,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Zoning":{"Description":"VA Zoning","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Insurence":{"CompanyName":"Geico","Address":null,"Phone":null,"ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"LandID":1,"ZoningID":1,"InsuranceID":1,"MapNum":"M-452658","TaxDistrict":8754,"LandArea":526.36,"Utilities":"Temp","IsRoadPaved":true,"SiteCondition":"GOOD","LandAssesmentValue":5.32,"BuildingAssesmentValue":4.56,"BuildingUsage":"Yes","Style":"NT","ExteriorWallMaterial":"TY","Roof":"KI","Basement":"GBH","BasementSize":452.3,"YearBuilt":"\/Date(1138766400000)\/","YearAddition":"\/Date(1329278400000)\/","YearRemodeled":"\/Date(1359864000000)\/","BedRoom":4,"FullBath":3,"HalfBath":2,"FirePlace":3,"BasementRoom":5,"Heating":"GRF","ConstructionQuality":"BETTER","PhysicalCondition":"GOOD","HasSwimmingPool":true,"SwimmingPoolSize":25.1,"WoodDeck":23.5,"Porch":21,"Garagae":2,"PurchasePrice":847.32,"PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1202788800000)\/","SalePrice":5871.2,"SaleDate":"\/Date(1327204800000)\/","IsManagementAssociation":true,"ManagementName":"GTR","ManagementAddress":"King Street","ManagementPhone":"58758","ManagementFee":500,"PolicyNumber":"P-0121","ID":2,"CreateDate":"\/Date(1357963200000)\/","CreatedBy":1,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},
        {"Land":{"Description":"Fairfax land 3","ID":3,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Zoning":{"Description":"VA Zoning","ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"Insurence":{"CompanyName":"Geico","Address":null,"Phone":null,"ID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreatedBy":null,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null},"LandID":1,"ZoningID":1,"InsuranceID":1,"MapNum":"M-452658","TaxDistrict":8754,"LandArea":526.36,"Utilities":"Temp","IsRoadPaved":true,"SiteCondition":"GOOD","LandAssesmentValue":5.32,"BuildingAssesmentValue":4.56,"BuildingUsage":"Yes","Style":"NT","ExteriorWallMaterial":"TY","Roof":"KI","Basement":"GBH","BasementSize":452.3,"YearBuilt":"\/Date(1138766400000)\/","YearAddition":"\/Date(1329278400000)\/","YearRemodeled":"\/Date(1359864000000)\/","BedRoom":4,"FullBath":3,"HalfBath":2,"FirePlace":3,"BasementRoom":5,"Heating":"GRF","ConstructionQuality":"BETTER","PhysicalCondition":"GOOD","HasSwimmingPool":true,"SwimmingPoolSize":25.1,"WoodDeck":23.5,"Porch":21,"Garagae":2,"PurchasePrice":847.32,"PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1202788800000)\/","SalePrice":5871.2,"SaleDate":"\/Date(1327204800000)\/","IsManagementAssociation":true,"ManagementName":"GTR","ManagementAddress":"King Street","ManagementPhone":"58758","ManagementFee":500,"PolicyNumber":"P-0121","ID":2,"CreateDate":"\/Date(1357963200000)\/","CreatedBy":1,"UpdateDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null}]);


        self.selectOption = ko.observableArray([2]);
```

Your Html

```
<select data-bind="options: list1, optionsText: function(item) {
                       return item.Land.Description 
                       },  optionsValue: function(item) {
                       return item.Land.ID 
                       },
                       optionsCaption: 'Select',
                        selectedOptions: selectOption">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another JSON name Lands using this one I populated the dropdownlist and it works fine. Only problem is when I edit data from my previous list1 the dropdownlist not selected any value. Following is my JSON and  Code: